# How to print a react-barcode component

Tags: reactjs, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a barcode created by react-barcode.

I have tried using methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708955/convert-react-barcode-to-pdf-format-to-print) but i cant seem to print the barcodes.

This is probably because an SVG is being rendered by react-barcode. I have also tried [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) and [react-easy-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-easy-print) but they seem to fail me too.

I also hope to make the barcode downloadable but nothing seems to work.The code i have below is what i have got so far.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BarCode from 'react-barcode';

```
class App extends Component {
  state= {
    value:''
  }

  onChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({value:e.target.value})
  }
  onClick=(e)=>{
    // LOGIC TO PRINT BARCODE COMES HERE
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={value} />
        <BarCode
          value={value}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Print Barcode</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: We need to see some code to see what you're doing wrong...

Comment: @markmoxx i have edited the question to show the current state of my code .

Answer (score 1):

This is what i used and it worked for me.
You will need html2canvas.

I'll be using React hooks for this, feel free to convert it to class based component if you want.

```
const App=(props)=>{

  const [value,setValue] = React.useState('');
  const wrapper_ref = React.useRef();

  const onChange=(e)=>{
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const onClick=(e)=>{
     const opt = {
        scale: 4
    }
    const elem = wrapper_ref.current;
    html2canvas(elem, opt).then(canvas => {
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
        iframe.name = 'printf'
        iframe.id = 'printf'
        iframe.height = 0;
        iframe.width = 0;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe)

        const imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'jpeg',
            quality: '1.0'
        })

        const style=`
            height:100vh;
            width:100vw;
            position:absolute;
            left:0:
            top:0;
        `;

        const url = `<img style="${style}" src="${imgUrl}"/>`;
        var newWin = window.frames["printf"];
        newWin.document.write(`<body onload="window.print()">${url}</body>`);
        newWin.document.close();

    });
  }

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" onChange={onChange} value={value} />
        {/**This wrapper is important*/}
        <div ref={wrapper_ref}>
            <BarCode
              value={value}
           />
        </div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Print Barcode</button>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This would work